# Moq - How to get a callback

Tags: .net, moq

I have a function with the following signature

I'm trying to mock this and get a value back

`Sub CreateEntry(ByVal description As String, response As Action(Of AsyncResponse(Of Response)))`

the second parameter is a callback and I'm trying to get it back by:

`serviceProxy.Setup(Sub(sp) sp.CreateEntry(It.IsAny(Of String),It.Isany(Of AsyncResponse(Of Response))))`

This gives me the following error:
Value of type 'AsyncResponse(Of Response)' cannot be converted to 'System.Action(Of AsyncResponse(Of Response))'

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to match an **AsyncResponse(of Response)** in your setup rather than an **Action(of AsyncResponse(of Response))**.

Try

```
serviceProxy.Setup(Sub(sp) sp.CreateEntry(It.IsAny(Of String),It.IsAny(Of Action(Of AsyncResponse(Of Response)))))
```